# Wait for return in multithreading

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I got class with method that wraps work with twitter api. I understand that I should use threads to work with Internet. But I'm a little bit new in this part of programming. So I decided that this would be enough.

```
-(NSArray*) getTweets:(NSString *)query {
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(anotherMethod:) withObject:query waitUntilDone:YES];
     return [self tweets];
}
```

And that's how I call it in main method:

```
NSString* query = @"query";
id<TwitterGetter> obj = [[className alloc] init];
NSArray* array = [obj getTweets:query];
```

But NSArray* is nil after this. What should I do to avoid this problem? I tried to read guides from apple, but looks like I didn't get it.

Comment: try to understand your question, but can not. Please explain in detail to get the answers

Comment: Consider that, in your main thread, array can be `nil` because `getTweets` hasn't even begun its work yet. You need some sort of synchronization between your two (or N) threads which share this kind of state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what exactly is going on we would need quite a lot more code, know what thread you are calling this on... Anyway, rather try some callback procedure. In your case `anotherMethod:` should call some callback method on main thread with your array parameter.

For instance this should be a good approach:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    //start some spinner or continue with application
    //even some locking mechanism might be needed so this method is not called multiple times
    [self getTweets:@"whatever"];
}
- (void)getTweets:(NSString *)query {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(anotherMethod:) withObject:query];
}
- (void)anotherMethod:(NSString *)query {
    //get tweets
    NSArray *tweets;
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(gotTweets:) withObject:tweets waitUntilDone:NO];
}
- (void)gotTweets:(NSArray *)tweets {
    //stop the spiner if needed
    //unlock if needed
    //do whatever with your data
}
```

About synchronisation:

You should always avoid doing loading and waiting on the main thread. If you need the screen to pause try adding some overlay (usually with some low alpha) and possibly add an `UIActivityIndicatorView` so the user can see some loading is in progress and block user interaction so he can not proceed into the application. Note if you are blocking the main thread for too long your application will be terminated (called watchdog) that is the main reason why you should do all the loading and requesting on a separate thread. Well, beside the reason the user may think the application is stuck and might kill it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I was thinking about callbacks, but regret them at first. And thanks for explaining why blocking main thread is bad.